# Using fontspec (which requires exp3-code.tex) makes lualatex slow

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I recently tried luatex (TeX Live on Mac) and found that if I use fontspec to load a font, it *really* slows down the compilation. My test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{ProximaNova}[
%     Path=fonts/,
%     UprightFont=*-Regular,
%     ItalicFont=*-RegularIt,
%     BoldFont=*-Bold,
%     BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt]

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

If I keep the font section commented out, it takes 0.7 seconds to generate the PDF. If I uncomment the font section, it takes 2.7 seconds. That's almost 4x.

A huge chunk of this 2 sec increase seems to be processing `expl3-code.tex` which someone else [complained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396838/while-compiling-expl3-code-tex-takes-more-time-than-the-others) about also.

Can this file be pre-compiled or something else to make it load faster?

Comment: As the question you link to notes, `expl3` is quite large, but on most systems the load time is pretty trivial (certainly less than a second). Other than building stuff into the format file there's not much that can be done to load material faster.

Comment: The complain about expl3 in the other question was a bug in miktex which has been resolved in the meantime. lualatex is slower than pdflatex - loading rather large fonts needs more time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With `\usepackage{expl3}` it takes 2.2 seconds, which is 80% of the time increase.

Comment: @Roxy Sure, but from a very low base. With LuaTeX, we have a load of Unicode data needed that's not in pdfTeX (where the load time is _really_ low). It's very hard to cut that down, as I said unless we went down the route of building `expl3` directly into the LaTeX kernel. That has been discussed, but there are issues with doing that globally ...