# Speed up compilation LuaLatex Windows TexLive

Tags: luatex, preamble, performance

I would like to pre-compile the preamble to speed up the compilation of my LuaLatex documents.

I have seen several questions regarding this (eg: [Question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469583/how-to-speed-up-lualatex-startup-with-fontspec?noredirect=1#comment1347982_469583), [Question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114742/speeding-up-compilation-using-precompiled-preamble-with-luatex), [Question 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55272/precompiled-header-in-lualatex-on-windows)), but all are either pretty old or do not work for me even with the very simple MWE that follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,lualatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
prova \quad $\alpha + \sum_i \beta_i $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Could you provide the most updated and reliable way to precompile the preamble with LuaLatex? I specifically work on Windows, distribution TexLive 2019, editor TexStudio, but I think a general guide to the "preamble precompilation" operation would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1: the solutions in questions 1, 2 and 3 produce the following error when trying to compile the file (after having precompiled the preamble):

```
! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Could you tell why the approaches in the related questions do not work for you? Do you get errors, or are the formats not applied, or something else?

Comment: @Marijn, sure. They produce errors, which I have specified in the question. I can also post the whole log if you think it is appropriate and useful.

Comment: @oibaFox: were you able to find a solution? I am currently stuck on the same issue.

Comment: @Gunter no, I am sorry. If you find one please let me know!